# Working with HorizontalScrollBar for TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have a Windows Form and it contains a TableLayoutPanel which I am filling with a dynamic number of custom made User Controls. There is only a single row, and a dynamic number of columns (which represent how many user controls we want). I've set the .AutoSize = true and the .GrowStyle = AddColumns so that the table expands as necessary. The problem I'm running into now is utilizing the horizontal scroll bar to see the rest of the columns.

Right now, it appears as if the horizontal scroll bar spans the entire table. Which means the far right side of the scroll bar cannot be seen. I'd like for this to span just to the end of the Form, and not the table.

I'd also like to adjust the scroll bar so that when it is clicked (both Large and Small clicks), the table displays only the next User Control.

Here's what I've tried:

```
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = true;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Visible = true;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.LargeChange = customControl.Width;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.SmallChange = customControl.Width;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = this.Width; // Here I am trying to set the max to the edge of the Form, and not the table, I don't believe this is the correct property.
```

Another thing, the way it's implemented now the horizontal scroll bar doesn't actually work. I can interact with it, but the table doesn't scroll.

Comment: That's how scrollbars work.  It does nothing because you let the TLP grow so there is nothing to scroll.  Set the form's AutoScroll property to True instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Hmm ok, that makes sense. So I maybe need to redesign the TLP. What I'm aiming for is a TLP that can hold plenty of columns, but only display let's say 5 at a time. And the user can scroll horizontally to see the next column.